# Cancel Exchange device administrator activation?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, exchange, active-sync, device-administrator

I was trying to add my Exchange account to my phone to confirm for a coworker that logging into the server was possible. I don't want to relinquish the device administrator controls as it's my personal phone, which is why I hadn't added it before and don't want to actually have it synced.

I was able to access the account to confirm, and was prompted to activate the device administrator, giving permissions to erase my data, set password rules, etc. I can hit cancel at this prompt, but am repeatedly re-prompted to activate whenever I try to access the Email app. I can't seem to figure out how to decline the activation or otherwise remove the Exchange account. Of course I could just activate, change my settings, then delete the account and change all of them back, but that would be a bit of a hassle and seems like bad design. Is there any way for me to remove the Exchange account/decline the device administrator prompt without activation?

Comment: Have you tried "Force Stopping" the app and clearing the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messed around with it a bit more and found a solution. I just had to go to Settings -> Accounts & sync to delete the Exchange account.